# jQuery Ancestor of nested selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a LI which a bunch of stuff in it

```
<li class="card">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <img src="/images/adv-ipanema.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                    <p class="place">Ipanema Beach</p>
                    <p class="steps">12,000 steps</p>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <div class="close"></div>
                    <div class="up"></div>
                    <div class="down"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

What I am trying to do is target the LI itself when the div class "up" is clicked.

I created a [simplified proof-of-concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/MYBZJ/2/) and was able to use parent().parent() but there must be a better way, no?  I tried parentsUntil('li') to no avail, unless I was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try** [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

**Description**
*For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.*

i.e.

```
$(this).closest("li") // or
$(this).closest(".card")
```

*N.B. [`parentsUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) will return all the parents **up to (but not including)** the selector provided*

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `closest` method:

```
var listItem = $(this).closest('li');
```